# What's the opposite of a 'static' website?

Tags: website, hosting

I attempted to explain that a particular challenge required the ability for a website to run scheduled background tasks, and therefore a static web site host would be inadequate, and a  website / webapp would instead be required? I am not sure what to say exactly?

Interestingly, same titled questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6293493/what-is-the-opposite-of-static), but completely different context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite of a static website would be a dynamic website.

Static websites consist of actual, physical, separate files that require physical intervention from a human being in order to be modified. The entire code used to represent any part of them must be hardcoded.

Dynamic websites are virtual pages built on the fly by some preexisting code, following each single request or responding to one made by a script or a user when one visits a web address.